# Как убрать кавычки в python

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная

```
output = subprocess.check_output("wp id", shell=True)
```

Она на выходе дает

```
b'131132'
```

Как убрать b и '

Comment: А зачем, они вам как-то мешают? Это нормальный вывод bytes-литерала принтом.

Comment: wp id меняется при каждой перезагрузке

Comment: и еще b и кавычки мещают для запуска скрипта

Comment: Как конкретно мешают-то?

Comment: не дают программе сменить обои, но мне человек ниже помог огромное ему спасибо

Comment: Так и не объяснили, как конкретно не дают. Голосую за закрытие вопроса как непонятный.

Comment: output = subprocess.check_output("wp id", shell=True)  на выходе b'131132' b и кавычки не дают запуститься скрипту я сам не знаю почему. нужно чтобы было только 131132

Comment: @olexxxi, а что после с `output` вы делаете, что это мешает работе скрипта? `b'131132'` -- это представление байтов, т.е. в `output` находится байты, а они при `print` пишутся с `b''`, но по факту `b''` там нет. Вам просто нужно байты привести к строке, т.е. `output = output.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @olexxxi, и, все же, можете ответить на вопрос по поводу проблемы работы скрипта? :) Это, кст, можно было привести в самом вопросе, чтобы добавить ему контекста, т.к. скорее всего ваш вопрос относится к [ошибке молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710) :) PS. добавляйте `@gil9red` в комментарии, чтобы я получал уведомление

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете привести данную переменную к типу ***Integer*** **:**

```
output = int(subprocess.check_output("wp id", shell=True))

print(output)

# 131132
```